# how to setup kafka source code to debug in IDE

Tags: eclipse, apache-kafka

I am trying to setup kafka in eclipse. I followed the documentation and installed the plugins required and imported the projects. I am trying to set the environment so that I am able to run the kafka server from eclipse and debug it line by line. 
My end goal is to contribute to kafka. To understand the code architecture I feel the need to be able to debug the code line by line and see what happens in the background. I tried reading the start script of kafka which sets some parameters to actually call the respective class.
for instance in kafka-server-start.sh
it sets( it sets more parameters than I mentioned)

`KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS = some value
 KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS = some value 
EXTRA_ARGS="-name kafkaServer -loggc"`

after that it is calling

```
exec $base_dir/kafka-run-class.sh $EXTRA_ARGS kafka.Kafka "$@"
```

Now i went into this script there are for loops which are adding some values to the classpath for e.g.( there are more than one for loop)

```
    for cc_pkg in "api" "runtime" "file" "json" "tools"
do
  for file in $base_dir/connect/${cc_pkg}/build/libs/connect-${cc_pkg}*.jar;
  do
    CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$file
  done
  if [ -d "$base_dir/connect/${cc_pkg}/build/dependant-libs" ] ; then
    CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$base_dir/connect/${cc_pkg}/build/dependant-libs/*
  fi
done
```

At the end how it is actually launching the kafka server

```
# Launch mode
if [ "x$DAEMON_MODE" = "xtrue" ]; then
  nohup $JAVA $KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS $KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS $KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS $KAFKA_JMX_OPTS $KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS -cp $CLASSPATH $KAFKA_OPTS "$@" > "$CONSOLE_OUTPUT_FILE" 2>&1 < /dev/null &
else
  exec $JAVA $KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS $KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS $KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS $KAFKA_JMX_OPTS $KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS -cp $CLASSPATH $KAFKA_OPTS "$@"
fi
```

Not sure how to tell all of this to eclipse when it runs. 
Let me know if I should put the whole script file here. Even if I can get a idea how to do that I can try.
I think I can pass this arguments in the arguments window, and there is a classpath tab as well in the debug configurations but should I add all the paths from the scripts in this window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass the server.properties file in the arguments. You can pass this from run configuration window and click apply and run/debug. This should get you going. You don't have to go through all the parameters and pass them. If you want to pass those parameters then you have to get the parameters like how Mathhias explained. But those parameters are not necessary to run kafka.

But simple solution is to right click on the main class of which ever project you want to run. For example if I want to run kafka server I will go in **core** project in the kafka main project

```
kafka-> core -> src.main.scala.kafka - > kafka.scala
```

Right click on this choose debug As then click debug configurations : in that window pass the path of server.properties file and click apply.
You can find server.properties file in the tar  where you found the start script.

Comment: Passing the server.properties is running kafka from IDE. Thanks for simplifying.

Answer (score 0):

First,  modify the Kafka script to `echo` the actual command:

```
echo $KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS $KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS $KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS $KAFKA_JMX_OPTS $KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS -cp $CLASSPATH $KAFKA_OPTS "$@"
```

After that, you need to edit the run configuration in Eclipse:

- The stuff from `$KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS $KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS $KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS $KAFKA_JMX_OPTS $KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS` and goes in field **JVM arguments** (in panel "Arguments").
- The `CLASSPATH` is configured via panel "Classpath"
- `$@` should contain the actual class containing `main` that is called (and maybe **Program arguments** that you can set in panel "Arguments")